# How to preview my slide-animations from a specific point per slide rather than all the way from the beginning (PowerPoint 2010)

Tags: powerpoint

So I'm designing some animation in one slide in powerpoint 2010. What happens is every time I do / add some new actions or objects, if I want to see the result, PowerPoint 2010 starts the animation all the way from the beginning. Is there a way to preview only the last few seconds of the animation.

Comment: Why has this been marked down? This is a legitimate and a very interesting question. It may involve using some VBA scripting to solve the issue.. Whoever marked it down, should at least explain his reasoning!

Comment: Probably because Stackoverflow is a forum for programming-related questions and your question (as originally posed) doesn't seem to have anything to do with programming.  I'd ask it in the sister forum, Superuser, where there's also a PowerPoint section.

Comment: Ok, well fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of me adding all the animations in one slide, I have decided to do in different slides.. and thus, I can preview each section individually.

This wasn't a programming question, so it should be moved to another forum though!